# Collapsing dataframe based on id, storing multiple values for variables into lists

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame in which I have an id variable `fruit` in the example. For some of the other variables, there is only one corresponding value to each id variable `taste`, `ranking` while for others, there are multiple `color`,`origin`.

I would like to collapse the data frame so that each id variable has one row. For the variables that have multiple values, I could ideally store them as a list.

However, I can't figure out a way to do this. Here is what I tried using `summarise` and `unique` for the variables with multiple values. However, I just got back the original data:

```
df %>%
  group_by(fruit) %>%
  summarise(ranking = mean(ranking),
            taste = first(taste),
            origin = unique(origin),
            color = unique(color))
```

**example data:**

```
ranking <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
fruit <- c("apple", "apple", "pear", "pear", "banana")
color <- c("red", "green", "red", "green", "yellow")
taste <- c("good", "good", "good", "good", "okay")
origin <- c("WA", "CA", "OR", "MX", "PR")

df <- data.frame(fruit, ranking, color, taste, origin)
```

[image]

**desired data"**

```
ranking <- c(1, 2, 3)
fruit <- c("apple", "pear", "banana")
color <- list((c("red", "green")), (c("red", "green")), (c("yellow")))
taste <- c("good", "good", "okay")
origin <- list(c("WA","CA"), c("OR", "MX"), c("PR"))
desired_df <- data.frame(fruit, ranking, taste, I(color), I(origin))
```

[image]

Is there an easy way to get this transformation done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `summarise` with `across`, store the `unique` elements in a `list` after doing a grouping by the columns of interest

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>%
      group_by(fruit, ranking, taste) %>% 
      summarise(across(c(color, origin), ~ list(unique(.))), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
 out
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  fruit  ranking taste color     origin   
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <list>    <list>   
1 apple        1 good  <chr [2]> <chr [2]>
2 banana       3 okay  <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
3 pear         2 good  <chr [2]> <chr [2]>
```

---

If the 'taste' should be the `first` element and `ranking` the `mean`

```
out <- df %>%
         group_by(fruit) %>%
         summarise(ranking = mean(ranking),
                   taste = first(taste),
                   across(c(color, origin), ~ list(unique(.))), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or use `base R`

```
aggregate(. ~ fruit + ranking + taste, unique(df), FUN = c)
```

-output

```
    fruit ranking taste      color origin
1  apple       1  good red, green WA, CA
2   pear       2  good red, green OR, MX
3 banana       3  okay     yellow     PR
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_split(fruit) %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% map_at(c("color", "origin"), ~ paste(.x, collapse = "-"))) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(ranking)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  fruit  ranking color     taste origin
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr> 
1 apple        1 red-green good  WA-CA 
2 pear         2 red-green good  OR-MX 
3 banana       3 yellow    okay  PR
```